# iOS app: tapping nonsubsite icon on sidebar makes icon of selected subsite inoperative

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

1. Tap the icon of a subsite like Stack Overflow on the sidebar.
2. Notice that something significant happens, namely opening up the most recent questions list for that subsite.
3. Tap the icon of another subsite.
4. Notice that the same significant thing happens, opening that subsite's question list.
5. Tap the icon of the original subsite.
6. Yep, the behavior is consistent: the original subsite's questions show up.
7. Tap a nonsubsite icon in one the sidebar, such as the message inbox, taking the content pane to the right of the sidebar out of the original subsite.
8. Tap the icon of the original subsite.
9. Notice that *nothing* happens, unlike every other time you've tried to switch to the original subsite.

This is jarring behavior, since tapping a subsite's icon always works to switch back to it, until it suddenly and inexplicably doesn't.

Could the subsite be collapsed (the four icons under the subsite's icon disappear like when you switch to another subsite) when a nonsubsite icon like the message inbox is tapped? Or perhaps could the subsite remain open and tapping on its icon take you back to what you were in the middle of before you tapped the nonsubsite icon?

- App Version: 1.4.5
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Cellular)
- OS Version: Version 9.3 (Build 13E233)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.4.6.

The problem is that the inbox and achievements used to appear as modal popups and now they don't and I missed some code that should have been switched over.

Namely, when you tap on an item like the "All Sites" or "About", the menu item stays highlighted a dialog pops up with the relevant information.  When you dismiss the dialog, you want the menu (and the app) to be back in its original state.  To handle this, we have logic that basically says "Don't collapse the site specific menu items when selecting X, Y, and Z, and when the dialog disappears reselect the original item."

Even though I had converted the inbox and achievements not to be modal, the logic was still there to keep the site open.